# Multiply two arrays with different dimensions using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I need a faster/optimised version of my current code:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array((1, 2, 3))
b = np.array((10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80))

print([i*b for i in a])
```

Is there any faster way to do this using numpy functions (maybe without reshaping and blowing up the whole thing)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like the [outer product](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html).

```
>>> np.outer(a, b)
array([[ 10,  20,  30,  40,  50,  60,  70,  80],
       [ 20,  40,  60,  80, 100, 120, 140, 160],
       [ 30,  60,  90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240]])
```

Comment: This is it, exactly ; )